# Skipping nested comments recursively in a scanner

Tags: c, recursion, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I'm writing a scanner for a compiler and have a function to skip comments whenever it sees them, I wanted to know how one would skip nested comments, i.e something like " hello "w" world", recursively, So far I have something like:

```
while ( current_char != '#' ){ // comments in this language starts with $# and end with #$)
      next_char(); // gets the next character in our file
```

}

Comment: How is `" hello "w" world"` a nested comment?

Comment: Note that in C, there are no nested comments.  `/* This is /* not a nested */ comment */` is *not* a nested comment.  It is a single comment follwed by a syntax error.

Comment: It is not a trivial exercise, so matching the quotes is essential too (and 'escaped' quotes that are part of the string, not a delimiter) because comment marks inside the string might not be actual comments. Maintain a stack of nesting.

Comment: You have the `recursion` tag for your question. For actual comments, in a language that allows nested block comments, using recursion to skip such comments is rather trivial: When seeing the comment-start sequence, call the "skip comment function" recursively.

Comment: The simple solution: recognise `/*` and `*/` and maintain a counter. Other solutions: recursive descent, or an explicit stack (of states)

Comment: I normally do this by keeping a count of how deeply the comment (or other) tags are nested.  When I see an open tag, increase the counter.  When I see a close tag, decrease the counter.  When the counter goes back to 0, I'm out of the comment(s).

Comment: Also, check out [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) and [bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bison) before actually hand-coding a scanner / parser. Computer language parsing is very much a solved problem.

Comment: @DevSolar But writing your own scanner/parser is the fun part of making a "compiler"... ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: If I wanted fun, I'd be doing it in C++ with Boost.Spirit. :-D

Comment: By doing nesting, you have increased the complexity of your language by quite a bit. See [parser generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators).

Answer (score 1):

#### Nested comments using a counter for the depth

The easiest method is to maintain a counter of the "comment depth":

- Every time you encounter `$#`, increment the counter;
- Every time you encounter `#$`, decrement the counter.

When the counter is 0, you're reading code; when the counter is 1 or more, you're reading a comment.

While reading a comment, ignore everything except `$#` and `#$`.

Example:

```
Code $# comment depth 1 $# comment depth 2 #$
comment depth 1 #$ code $# comment depth 1 #$ code
```

#### Escaping characters in strings

You mentioned the following example:

```
" hello "w" world"
```

Let me put some emphasis on the following advice:

**Do not allow nested comments if the begin-comment and the end-comment symbols are identical.**

Otherwise, there would be no way to distinguish between the two following situations:

```
Situation 1:  "comment" code "comment"
Situation 2:  "comment "nested comment" comment"
```

Note that the symbol `"` is usually used for strings, not for comments. There is no such thing as a "nested string" (what would that mean??). However, there is such a thing as "escaped characters in a string". Indeed, what if you want a string to contain the character `"`? The usual approach is to reserve an escaping character; characters directly following the escaped character are not interpreted. So you could write the following string:

```
" hello \"w\" world"
```

Satisfyingly, you can note that StackOverflow's automatic syntax-colouring correctly coloured all the string in green; whereas the previous string without the `\` was not correctly coloured.